# How to make authentication login using GitHub in angular app?

Tags: angular, authentication, github

I tried to solve this problem through fire base but there is a problem in authorized domains that I can't replace it by my domain. Is there any way to solve this problem through fire base or any other way?

Comment: If you have tried to solve this, then edit your post to include the code you have written.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a Firebase project and enable the Github sign-in method, and sign up like this.

```
return this.af.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider())
```

Comment: The problem in Firebase project that i can't change default authorized domain to my website domain

Comment: You don't need to change default to your domain. Go to Authentication / Sign-in method and scroll down, and add another authorized domain.